# Android Studio doesn't recognize Android Devices on MacOS Sierra

Tags: android-studio, adb, macos-sierra

I have always been able to get Android Studio to recognize my USB android devices in the past. However, this morning I upgraded to MacOS Sierra. Now, when I plug in an android device android studio doesn't see it. And my phone acts like it is plugged into a wall and not a computer. Usually, when I plug into a computer, I get the an option in the notification/dropdown menu to select a PTP or MTP connection. I am not getting that option.

I'm running Android Studio 2.2.3 and macOS Sierra v10.12 on a Macbook Pro.

I have tried different cables, different android devices, restarting my computer, still no dice.

If I run `./adb devices` from the `/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/` directory then I get nothing but `List of devices attached` with a blank line underneath.

[image: No Connected Devices Error Message]

Comment: I had this problem at one point.  Make sure that your usb debug options in developer settings of the device is not off.  Somehow that happened to me one day, once I flipped it back on, Android Studio picked up on the device

Comment: Checked and double checked. It's on...

Comment: A few minutes ago with the same problem. I solved it suing this command: ./adb reconnect